# Secondary dropdown menu within a dropdown menu not showing

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting a secondary dropdown menu to appear to the right of one of the dropdown links I hover over but it does not appear..

I have positioned the secondary dropdown menu accordingly using margins.. If you change the width of the *.subDropdown* class to a value e.g. 100px, you can see the dropdown is where it should be.. so I'm not sure why it does not change when I code in a 'hover' event..

https://jsfiddle.net/yje82den/

Can't see what I'm missing..

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="navbtn">
<p>MENU BUTTON</p>

<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdownitem">Link 1</div>
    <div class="dropdownitem">Link 2</div>
    <div class="dropdownitem" id="sub">Link 3 &#8594;</div>
    <div class="subDropdown">
        <div class="dropdownitem">Link 4</div>
        <div class="dropdownitem">Link 5</div>
        <div class="dropdownitem">Link 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.navbtn {
background-color: #009337;
max-width: 250px;   
}

.dropdown {
height:0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: height 0.5s;
}

.dropdownitem {
background-color: #00bf48;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
padding: 10px;  
transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.dropdownitem:hover {background-color:#43e27f;}

.subDropdown .dropdownitem {
background-color: #23f171;
}

.subDropdown {
position: fixed;
margin: -39px 0 0 250px;
height: 120px;
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
transition: width 0.5s;
}

.navbtn:hover .dropdown {height:115px;}
#sub:hover .subDropdown {width: 250px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown `.subDropdown` is not a descendant of `#sub`, so selector `#sub:hover .subDropdown` won't work.

Instead you can use the [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`), as the sub-dropdown is placed immediately after the `#sub` div in the DOM.

Also, you can add `.subDropdown:hover` on the same styles to ensure that as you hover over the child links, the menu remains open.

```
#sub:hover + .subDropdown,
.subDropdown:hover {
  width: 250px;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yje82den/2/

Comment: Ah thank you Nisarg. Funny the difference 1 symbol can make.. I am yet  to wrap my head around the css selectors so I might go and do that now.

Comment: @SteveyG Yup they can be tricky initially. MDN has some great articles here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors

Comment: May I ask (as I just noticed) - when I hover over any of the secondary dropdown links, the menu minimises again..

Just wondering if you know what's causing that?

Comment: @SteveyG Yeah, you'd need to add one more rule there which keeps the menu open when `.subDropdown` is hovered upon. I just updated the answer.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yje82den/3/), if you need to add more links-sublinks, you will need to change `height` to `auto` on rule `.navbtn:hover .dropdown`.